# How to delete folders from GIT?

Tags: git, directory, bitbucket, git-rm

I need to remove 2 folders in BitBucket:

I used command:
`git rm folder1 folder2`

And got error:

> Fatal: not removing "folder1" recursively without -r

Comment: As the error says, try `git rm -r folder1 folder2`.

Comment: Did you read and understand the relevant parts of https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `git rm folder1 folder2` to `git rm -r folder1 folder2` to remove a directory.

`git rm --help`

> -r
>
> ```
> Allow recursive removal when a leading directory name is given.
> ```

Comment: yes it work, thank you ;)